# PHP Login (Session Issues)

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, session-variables

My MYSQL PHP is correct but when I login then, page **check.php** redirects me on login.page again. For verification with page redirects me I use `*?session*` in URL. Might it is because my session is not activate. How? Even all tags is corrects.

> is there any other issues? Please help.
>
> advance thank you.!!!

**LOGIN PAGE**

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
session_start(); 

if (isset($_SESSION["Mobile"]) && isset($_SESSION["LoggedIn"])) 
 {  
header("Location: index.php"); 
exit();
 }  
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {  
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "id4915357_regis", "Demo@1653", "id4915357_reg");

if ($data->num_rows > 0)
 {  
$_SESSION["Mobile"] = $Mobile; 
$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = 1;  
header ("Location: index.php"); 
exit();
 } else { 
echo "<script>alert(' Invalid Credentials')</script>";  
 } 
 }  

?>
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US"> <head>
<title>MyWebsite</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body> <form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile" value="1234567890"/>
<input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Passwors"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CHECK.PHP**

```
<?php 

session_start();    
if (!isset($_SESSION["Mobile"]) || !isset($_SESSION["LoggedIn"]))
   {            
 header("Location: login.php?session");
    exit(); 
   }
?>
```

Comment: You have add `session()` insde the code segment where you have put comment as `remember me not checked`, may be you are not checking the remember checkbox. Please check yourself where the control goes, whether its on `if` or `else` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `session_start()` function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.
and the page should save with `.php` extension

Answer (score 0):

**session_start()** should be at the topmost of your codes. You `should not output anything before calling it` else it will fail. Same goes for **setcookie()** and **header();**

Looking at your code, I think it's better if you move your php block at the top of your html content.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169429/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-blue-session-is-not-working-even-using-correct-forma).